# How to reuse SOAP/XML-RPC requests in a single JMX file

Tags: soap, jmeter, reusability

I have a Login SOAP request on Jmeter as a "Set UP" and a set of SOAP requests after that with in "do Test" simple controller and then the "Tear down".

Would wish to again use the Login SOAP request, to start another set of tests on the same Jmx file. How do I do that, is there any way out to call the Login action, rather than copy/paste of the existing Login request?

In general is there any way out to reuse the requests/samplers within the same Jmx file?

Answer (score 4):

To re-use code, you want to use the MODULE controller, as detailed in the [manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller).

Comment: Hi, Thank U very much! Also in addition to Module controller, we could use "Parameterized controller" which is available as a plugin @ http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/ParameterizedController which could be really useful!     Have fun

Comment: Glad to help, and welcome to SO.  If this answer resolved your question, please consider marking it as a solution.

Answer (score 2):

There are several options to reuse logic in JMeter:

- "Module controller" (see BlackGaff's answer)
- ["Include controller"](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller), which allows you to read in an external.jmx file
- ["Parametrized Controller"](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/ParameterizedController) from the jmeter-plugins project (not part of the JMeter core), which builds on the Module controller and allows to parametrize it